# Generic Rails XML response to successful AJAX action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, paperclip

I think this should be an easy syntax question, but I'm not sure if my approach is correct.  I'm using paperclip to accept a file upload from Flash.  The action successfully creates the object and saves the upload, but when it tries to generate an XML response with the default XML generator I think it chokes trying to include the paperclip attachment in the XML file.  Rails shows a 406 error and Flash throws the I/O error.

I found [a good resource on embedding paperclip attachments in XML](http://tenmiles.com/blog/2010/08/image-handling-in-ror-api-using-paperclip/) but this is total overkill.  All flash needs is a success or failure message.  Something like:

```
def jpg_stream
  @photo = Photo.new(:name => params[:name], :uploaded => Time.now)
  @photo.image = params[:image]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.save
      format.xml  { "<success/>" }
    else 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What should this line be?

```
format.xml  { "<success/>" }
```

**EDIT**

This is the error stack trace.  I think Rails has no problems returning whatever is generated, the 406 error means the browser/Flash will not accept the response.

```
Started POST "/generate_jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-25 12:59:24 -0700
  Processing by PhotosController#jpg_stream as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Test snapshot", "stream_id"=>"1", "Filename"=>"this.jpg",     "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::
Http::UploadedFile:...
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/Users/Sam/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110125-4048-zqbu60.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
  ←[1m←[35mAREL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "photos" ("name", "description", "stream_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at") VALUES ('Test snapshot', '2011-01-25 19:59:24.630999', 1, '2011-01-25 19:59:24.687002', '2011-01-25 19:59:24.687002', 'this.jpg', 'application/octet-stream', 12251, '2011-01-25 19:59:24.651000')
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving .../system/images/86/original/this.jpg
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 108ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a simpler version first: `render :xml => "<success/>"`. I.e., drop `respond_to` completely, leave only

```
if @photo.save
  render :xml => "<success/>"
else 
  render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I'm not sure about all nuances of `respond_to` (don't use it myself), but doing `format.xml  { "<success/>" }` might require a erb template from you.

Including error stacktrace would be nice too.